# Cauchy product on topological rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, topological-groups

Let $R$ be any commutative Hausdorff topological ring. I am looking for a preferably general condition on sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that the equation $$ \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n x_k y_{n-k} $$
is valid. Is it possible to be general enough to cover the cauchy product of absolutely convergent series of real numbers as well as the ordinary product in any topological ring of formal power series (considered as the $(X)$-adic completion of a polynomial ring)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Interesting question. But I doubt that it is possible to cover the case of absolute convergent series of real (or Banach algebra valued) sequences. The reason is that a) the usual proofs are analytic, use non-obvious inequalities etc (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), b) even for real sequences no purely algebraic conditions are known for the Cauchy product to be convergent. But there is a general condition for adic rings (which includes rings of formal power series). Are you interested?

Comment: Yes, even the restriction to adic rings would be really interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n$ is the limit of the sequence $k \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{k} x_n$ (if it exists, which I assume), similarily for $y$, hence $\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y_n\right)$ is the limit of the sequence $C : k \mapsto \left(\sum_{n=0}^{k} x_n \right) \cdot \left(\sum_{n=0}^{k} y_n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{2k} \left(\sum_{p,q \leq k, p+q=n} x_p y_q\right)$. We want to compare this with the limit of the sequence $D : k \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{k} \sum_{p+q=n} x_p y_q$. We have

$C(k)-D(2k)=\sum_{n=0}^{2k} \sum_{p+q=n, p>k \vee q>k} x_p y_q=\sum_{n=0}^{2k} \sum_{k<p \leq n} x_p y_{n-p} +\sum_{n=0}^{2k} \sum_{k<q \leq n} x_{n-q} y_q$.

Now assume that $R$ has the $I$-adic topology for some ideal $I$. Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $x_p \to 0$ for $p \to \infty$, we have $x_p \in I^m$ for large $p$. Similarily, we have $y_p \in I^m$ for large $p$. From the above formula we see that $C(k) - D(2k) \in I^m$ for large $k$. This proves that $C(k) - D(2k) \to 0$ for $k \to \infty$. Similarily one proves that $C(k) - D(2k+1) \to 0$ (using $\sum_{n=0}^{k+1} y_n$). Thus, $D(2k)$ and $D(2k+1)$ have the same limit as $C$. It follows that $D$ converges, and has the same limit as $C$.

Summary: In an adic topological ring, if $\sum_n x_n$ and $\sum_n y_n$ converge, then also their Cauchy product converges and the formula holds.

Fun remark: In a cocomplete $\otimes$-category, the formula

$$\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} X_n \otimes \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} Y_n = \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigoplus_{p+q=n} X_p \otimes Y_q$$
holds without any conditions. I love these $\otimes$-categories ...

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Remark: This also works when the topology is induced by a translation-invariant ultrametric. For arbitrary metrics it does not work.